# Find which node of firebase is updated

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have set my firebase database like this

[image]

I want the name of node where new booking arrived. I have set child listener for this but it is only showing the previous child name.
here is my code

```
DatabaseReference reference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("bookings");
    reference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {
            Toast.makeText(ExampleService.this, "DataSnapshot 1: "+previousChildName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "DataSnapshot 2: "+ previousChildName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "DataSnapshot 3: "+ snapshot.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "DataSnapshot 4: "+ previousChildName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "DataSnapshot error: "+ error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show the key of the new child, you want to use `snapshot.getKey()`:

```
Toast.makeText(ExampleService.this, "DataSnapshot 1: "+snapshot.getKey(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

I highly recommend keeping the [reference documentation for `DataSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot) and the guide on [listening for child events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#child-events) handy.

Comment: Thank you. It helped me to solve the problem